# How to make PostBuildEvent work in Project Rider

Tags: visual-studio-2015, rider

Just started to use Project Rider - Great potential.

I have PostBuildEvent commands defined in several of my visual studio projects.
I wonder if anyone knows how I make it work project rider.

Answer (score 3):

You can use AfterBuild target from MSBuild. PostBuildEvent it is Visual Studio specific way. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msbuild/2005/10/12/how-to-beyond-prebuild-and-postbuild-steps/

Answer (score 0):

After 4 years using Rider I have better understanding about how Rider works.
Project in C# are configured by the .csproj files - it is maybe "invented" by VS but Rider know as well to read csproj file - so in particular - it knows to run the PostBuildEvent.

Answer (score 0):

From [Rider doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Build_Process.html#rs_build):

> The projects that are not affected by changes are skipped completely,
> including all additional build logic. If you want to execute pre-build
> and post-build events and/or BeforeBuild and AfterBuild MSBuild
> targets for skipped projects, use the corresponding checkboxes on the
> Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolset And Build page of JetBrains
> Rider settings

So, not always events are executed by default.